# Static Wireless IP - Can Only Access Internet Using IPs

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, dns, static-ip

I am using Lubuntu 12.10 as a local server and I am trying to get a static IP from my wireless network. I don't have a problem connecting to the server, I can ssh and view webpages on the same network using 192.168.2.xx, and also with my external IP when on another network.

I change the settings by:
1. Clicking on the wireless tab, selecting my network, and clicking edit.
2. I then click the IPv4 tab and change DHCP to Manual.
3. I add an address: 192.168.2.xx, mask: 255.255.255.0, gateway: 192.168.2.1.
4. I click save.

My problem is I cannot access the internet using domain names when on the Lubuntu machine. I can ping Google's IP Address, but not the domain name. The same thing happens in Chromium.

Ping result: `ping: unknown host google.com`
Chromium result: `Error 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED): Unknown Error.`

I change my network settings back to DHCP from Manual and it works.

I tried editing `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and adding `nameserver 192.168.2.xx`, but that did not help.

I also tried adding the following to /etc/network/interfaces (but have it commented out now)
`auto wlan0`
`iface wlan0 inet manual`

My `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` are empty. `/etc/network/interfaces` only has `eth0` data in it.

Comment: Can you: ping -c3 8.8.8.8? When you edited Network Manager, what did you use for DNS nameservers? Usually, the gateway address is sufficient: 192.168.2.1.

Comment: Yes that ping worked. I am not sure I put anything for DNS nameservers. I did not know I had to. What goes there?

Comment: Oops, just reread your comment, I am trying it with the gateway as the DNS nameserver.

Comment: That was easy :). Thank you. You can create an answer so I can accept it, or if you think this is too obvious or something I can delete it.

Comment: If all you need is the server to have static IP it would be much easier to assign that from router. If you have access to it of course.

Comment: Yes, I read about that and tried looking for it in my router settings. I couldn't find it. (probably because I am not totally sure what I was looking for)

Comment: You can use Google's DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set up DNS nameservers. I suggest the gateway and Google's DNS: 192.168.2.1 and 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 1):

- If `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty then you probably need to restore the symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf` -> `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.  A quick way to do this is to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.
- After setting IPv4 Settings | Method to `Manual`, add the correct IPv4 addresses for you nameservers to the "DNS servers" field.
- Make sure that `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` contains only the following standard resolvconf header.

`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
 #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`

- Make sure that `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` contains no `nameserver` lines.
- Delete the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` if present and make `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` a symbolic link to `/dev/null`. Do `sudo ln -nsf /dev/null /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`.
- Remove the `auto wlan0` and `iface wlan0` stanzas from `/etc/network/interfaces`.
- Make sure `/etc/network/interfaces` contains `auto lo` and `iface lo inet loopback` lines.
- Your `/etc/hosts` should not be empty.

`/etc/hosts` should contain the following (with your hostname instead of HOSTNAME).

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   HOSTNAME
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: After chili555's answer, everything seems to match what you described. Thanks for the detail.